# web browser delete element's outer html

Tags: c#, outerhtml

I have a C# application which has a web browser, navigating to a specified page by default.

What I want to do is when the document has completely loaded, select a html element by tag name(not ID/Class) and then delete the html outside of it but I have tried for some time and still didn't success..

This is my event and where I got so far

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var elementToDelete = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form");
    }
```

I want to select that form element which has no CLASS/ID and delete all html code that is outside of it(outer-html) so it will be the only thing visible on the page.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to delete an element, but then after your code you say that you want to delete everything outside of "form". I'm not sure which you actually want, but you can do the second with the following.

First, note that `elementToDelete` is actually a collection, not a single element, so we need to get a single element.

```
var formElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form");
var elementToSave = formElements.FirstOrDefault();
if(elementToSave == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("No element named 'form'");
```

You can then set the `Document.DocumentText` property to the `InnerHtml` property of "form". You should probably wrap up the inner HTML so that it's a valid page, but this should work:

```
webBrowser1.Document.DocumentText = elementToSave.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake that I fixed now. So this you gave me is to dissplay only the form without outer html right?